# Voicemail-only option for Google Voice

Tags: google-voice

I need a voicemail number for my workers to call in sick or leave messages. I don't wish to talk to them, I just want to be able to listen to their messages. I bought a magicJack thinking it would do what I want along with Google Voice, but no luck. magicJack is not under any carrier.

I'm left with no free options; even prepaid phones must charge some money every month or they disconnect your number.

I just want to buy a number for voicemail, no real forwarding. Can I do that with Google Voice or combining it with another option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google voice does work like that - though you need a number to initially set it up IIRC. Once thats done, just disassociate your number from the line, and it should just work as a voice mail box. You might also be able to get a number off something like [ipkall](http://www.ipkall.com/), and use that with a SIP account. Planned properly this should be free.

[image]

You can then set do not disturb to have all your calls sent to your voice mailbox

Comment: i already have a working account with my old magic jack number. so i can just de-associate it and keep the number they give me for voicemail forwarding? they gave me another free number (google) that rings my phone, but what if my other phone is not active any more? will people stil go to the voice mail?

Comment: ahh, clarified on what you want, and updated